# chrome extension file input in popup

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, file-upload

I am still new to how chrome extensions work and i found out that its not possible to have file input in the popup dialog due to the fact that the moment I take the focus off popup the popup window will close. So, I am thinking how to deal with this problem. I have two solutions that I am considering:

1. open a new tab and run the file dialog from there
2. add the file input to the context of the current page

They both do the exact same thing but which one would be more reliable. I am guessing the first one but I would want to hear experiences of others.

Also, I have been thinking couple steps ahead and I see that there won't be any way to access the popup wherever I open it, so how am i suppose to handle that kind of a situation?

Thanks,
Gasim

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are in search of this.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fileBrowserHandler.html